# Dollars to pennies

Tags: php, regex, decimal, currency

I'm having some trouble with Regex I'm trying to take a money amount like $28.84 and store it into my database as pennies. Right now I'm using this

```
$amount="$28.84";
$amount_number= ereg_replace("[(^0-9)(.)(0-9){2}]", "", $amount ); //return a decimal
$store_amount = $amount_number*100; //get number of pennies
```

I'm also trying to strip the number of "," " " and anything not a decimal number.

Comment: I would need a little more information on error conditions.  In other words, have you already checked whether <code>$amount</code> is in proper format?  What if there are too many or too few decimal places?  Invalid characters?  It looks like you're saying that anything other than a digit is simply stripped, but I'm trying to ensure that is really what you want.

Comment: Don't use ereg: it's deprecated.

Comment: @Andrew, validation is being done in javascript, to ensure numbers are in `$10.00` format I would like to factor in what if java is disabled strip all none numeric and force 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Mark. What has replaced ereg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are going about this wrong.  Why not replace the dollar sign, use `floatval` and then multiply by 100.  Then use `intval` to get rid of the decimal from the result, as you don't want fractions of a penny.

```
$amount = intval(floatval(str_replace("$", "", $amount))*100);
```

I didn't test it, but something like this should work.

Check out here for how some people handle currency stuff.  They have a lot of methods:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: I'm not sure - you can try it, or replace commas with an empty string too.  Just add another `str_replace` around the first.

Comment: + 1 since using regular expression for arithmetic procedures is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the input has been validated already, remove all non-digits then convert the result to an integer using `int_val`.

Personally I would reject all non-standard inputs such as `$12.3`. In my opinion when dealing with money you should be strict on what inputs you accept and not try to guess what was meant.

Comment: This is assuming that there are always exactly two digits after the decimal point. Otherwise 23.4 and 2.34 will be converted to the same integer.

Comment: +1.  Some links: http://www.google.com/search?q=floating+point+limitations http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Validation is being done on the javascript side of things which should work great unless someone has disabled javascript and is being stupid.

Comment: @BandonRandon: Client validation can help give a nice user experience but it offers no security. You should **always** revalidate on the server side.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: When dealing with money I feel it is better to reject invalid inputs rather than guess what was meant. I've updated my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
[(^0-9)(.)(0-9){2}]
```

should be

```
[0-9.]
```

You cannot use () inside []. The only special character that can be used inside [] is the ^ character.

Answer (score 1):

```
$amount = "$28.84";
$amount = preg_replace("#([^0-9\.]+)#", "", $amount);
$amount = explode(".", $amount);
$amount = (intval($amount[0]) * 100) + intval($amount[1]);
echo $amount; //2884
```

Comment: This answer was helpful to me, it solved an issue I was having. Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = "$28.84";
$amount_number = floatval(substr($amount,1));
$store_amount = $amount_number*100.0;
```

You can just use `substr` to remove the dollar sign.  If you really want to use a regex, try this:

```
$amount = "$28.84";
$amount_number = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $amount));
$store_amount = $amount_number*100.0;
```

You need to use `floatval` to convert the amount from a string to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the dollar sign and multiple by 100?

> preg_replace(/\$/, "", $amount);

Comment: I'll need to remove comma's too.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning second line to as follows:

```
$amount_number= ereg_replace("[^0-9.]", "", $amount );
```

Comment: I tried that, this strips the decimal too, so $5.00 become 500 and therefore returns 500000 which is the pennies for $500 and not $5

Comment: If the . is stripped then amount need not be multiplied by 100 to convert it to pennies.